# Laravel Eloquent map in query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, frameworks

I have a problem with mapping objects in a Laravel eloquent query.

1. How to map relations in a query builder.
2. How to connect two separate collections.
   For example. Having models:

```
    class CartProduct extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'quantity',
            'cart_id',
            'product_id',
            'unit_price',
            'product_code'
        ];
    
        function product(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
        }
    
        function cart(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Cart::class);
        }
    
    }
    
    class Cart extends Model
    {
        function productsInCart()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(CartProduct::class);
        }
    
        public function products()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(
                Product::class,
                'cart_products',
                'cart_id',
                "product_id");
        }
    }
    
    class Product extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [
            'name',
            'code',
            'description',
            'price',
        ];
    
    }
```

The tasks are:

1. Get a set of products that are in the same cart (doesn't matter which one) as $product_id (excluding $product_id)
2. Get a set of products that were in any cart together with $product_id (excluding $product_id, without duplications)

I would solve it like this:

1.

```
public function task_one($product_id)
{
    return $products = CartProduct::where('product_id', $product_id)->first()->cart->products
        ->filter(function (Product $p) use ($product_id) {
            return $p->id !== $product_id;
        });
}
```

2. 

```
public function task_two($product_id)
{
    $cartProducts = CartProduct::where('product_id', $product_id)->get();
    $products = collect(new Product);

    foreach ($cartProducts as $cartProduct) {
        $productsInCart = $cartProduct->cart->products
            ->filter(function (Product $p) use ($product_id) {
                return $p->id !== $product_id;
            });
        $products = $products->merge($productsInCart);
    }
    return $products->unique();
}
```

However, the 2nd function seems to be awful. How can I do this properly, to achieve fast execution and a good style of code?

Is there any method to "map" the whole collection to related model objects? For example by

```
$carts = CartProduct::getByProductId($product_id)->"mapByRelationship('cart)";
//The result should be a collection od Carts
$products = CartProduct::getByProductId($product_id)->"mapByRelationship('cart)"->"mapByRelationship('products')"->unique(); 
//The result should be the same as task_two($product_id);
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Your logic seems wrong.  CartProduct is acting as a pivot model.  Your Cart should not have a direct relationship with Product, so no products() function in the Cart model

Answer (score 0):

I think I have done this `Controller-Model` Relationship.

***Controller:***

```
class MakeAWishController extends Controller
{
    public function getMakeAWishes(Request $request)
    {
        $limit = (int) ($request->limit ?? 1);
        $offset = (int) ($limit * (($request->page ?? 1) - 1));

        $wishes = MakeAWish::with('product')
                    ->offset($offset)->limit($limit)->where('product_quantity', '>' , '0')->get()
                    ->map(function ($wish) {
                        $wish->children_image = asset(Storage::url($wish->children_image));
                        if(!empty($variant = $wish->product->variant())) {
                            $wish->product->variant_id = $variant->variant_id;
                            $wish->product->variant_price = $variant->variant_price ?? "0.00";
                            $wish->product->variant_compare_at_price = $variant->variant_compare_at_price ?? "0.00";
                        }
                        return $wish;
                    });

        $response = [
            'status' => 200,
            'data' => $wishes
        ];

        return response()->json($response);
    }
}
```

***Model:***

```
class MakeAWish extends Model
{
    protected $collection = 'make_a_wishes';

    protected $fillable = [
        'children_name',
        'children_name_for_isis',
        'age',
        'country',
        'children_image',
        'product_id',
        'quantity'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'product_id' => 'string'
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Product::class, 'product_id', 'product_id');
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderHistory::class, 'type_id', '_id');
    }

    public function orderCount()
    {
        return $this->orders()->where('type', 'M')->count();
    }
}
```